# ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 Azure Ad Certificate Format Issue .Cer to .PFX

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to implement SSO SAML authentication in .Net Core 3.1 with Azure AD
Following this Guid [Here](https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2)

My questions are:
Can I remove the code that refers to SigningCertificatePassword (.pfx file) and add reference to my .cer file because Azure Ad only Give .cer/.pem files and while ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 only support .PFX file so How can I convert those files?

Comment: Manthan did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

A `PFX` is a complete bundle (Keystore) consisting of a `certificate` and its `private key`. So if you have got both then you can add those entities to the Keystore.

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey private_key.pem -in certificate.cert -export -out keystore.pfx
```

Comment: But I did not see Any private key Available in Azure Ad where Can I Get this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @manthanshah ? I am at the exact same point!

Answer (score 0):

A PXT certificate contain both the privat and public key. a DER certificate only contain the public key.

You need to create you own PXT certificate for your application or possible use the same certificated used for TLS/SSL.

.NET sample code which show how to create a certificate in .NET:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/blob/b6dd1f8211015a5b366ce2b062dde481e38848fc/src/FoxIDs.SampleHelperLibrary/TestCertificate.cs

```
using (var rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
{
    var certRequest = new CertificateRequest(
        $"CN={cn}, O=FoxIDs",
        rsa,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

    certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(certRequest.PublicKey, false));

    certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(
        new X509KeyUsageExtension(
            X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyAgreement,
            false));

    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var cert = certRequest.CreateSelfSigned(now.AddDays(-1), now.AddYears(100));

    File.WriteAllBytes(PfxFile(path, cn), cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
    File.WriteAllBytes(CrtFile(path, cn), cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));
}
```

Comment: Where in the code that you put there, does it load or reference the .cer file or Federation Metadata XML file which are available from Azure AD (as in the original posters query) ? Surely Azure AD will want the data relevent to the application that you are trying to authenticate against?